# Using for loop and list for value extraction

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a code that extracts data from satellite observation nc files in total of 8 stations.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = Dataset('rainfall.nc', 'r')
dims = data.dimensions
ndims = len(dims)
vars = data.variables
nvars = len(vars)
attrs = data.ncattrs
lon = data.variables['lon'][:]
lat = data.variables['lat'][:]
```

The longitude and latitude of desired stations are as follow:

```
A=(46.28, 38.08)
B=(49.62, 37.32)
C=(51.50, 36.65)
D=(47.00, 35.33)
E=(51.32, 35.68)
F=(51.67, 32.62)
G=(51.55, 30.68)
H=(52.60, 29.53)
```

For each station (from A to H) I have to do the following 6 line coding task in order to achive the data (the following code is example of "A" station), where the ?? is the desired variable such as rainfall or etc. :

```
long_location,lat_location = (A) "= (46.28, 38.08)"
sq_dist_lat = (lat - lat_location)**2
sq_dist_lon = (lon - long_location)**2
min_index_lat = sq_dist_lat.argmin()
min_index_lon = sq_dist_lon.argmin()
variable = data.variables['rainfall'][min_index_lat, min_index_lon]
```

I have created a list as follow:

```
locations = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H]
```

however, I need a 'for' loop to do the 6 line task which I mentioned above to all 8 stations and print a data as an array with 8 columns. I will appreciate it if anyone can help me

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there expected output?

Comment: there are many misses in your question - what is the variables `lat` and `lon`? what the meaning of the last line? to simplify the question - Do you search for the minimum point that match the condition for lat and the minimum point that match the condition of long?

Comment: @YossiLevi I have edited the question. I need to repeat the 
" long_location,lat_location = (A)
sq_dist_lat = (lat - lat_location)**2
sq_dist_lon = (lon - long_location)**2
min_index_lat = sq_dist_lat.argmin()
min_index_lon = sq_dist_lon.argmin()
variable = data.variables['rainfall'][min_index_lat, min_index_lon]
"
for each of 8 stations (from A to H). each of these will lead to a different "variable" array

Comment: But you still haven't clarify what the variable `lat` and `lon` means - provide full code includes them

Comment: @YossiLevi ... lat and long are longitude and latitude variables of NC files which are constant and can not be changed ... each cross-section of longitude and latitude is a variable data ... the code I write read the station location and find the nearest longitude and latitude and extracted its variable value

Answer (score 0):

I face an error of `'float' object has no attribute 'argmin'`, I guess that you want to find the closest point between the points (A-H) to given point (`lat` and `lon`) if not - then please clarify input and expected output.

for that, you can use this piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
A=(46.28, 38.08)
B=(49.62, 37.32)
C=(51.50, 36.65)
D=(47.00, 35.33)
E=(51.32, 35.68)
F=(51.67, 32.62)
G=(51.55, 30.68)
H=(52.60, 29.53)

locations = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H]

lon = 51
lat = 35

closest_point = locations[np.argmin([np.sqrt((item[0]-lon)**2 + (item[1]-lat)**2) for item in locations])]
print(closest_point)
```

output:

```
(51.32, 35.68)
```

If this is not what you were looking for, take my answer as an hint